# How to show an empty view with a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, no-data

I am used to put an special view inside the layout file as [described in the `ListActivity` documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) to be **displayed when there is no data**. This view has the id `"android:id/empty"`.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/no_data" />
```

I wonder how this can be done with the new [`RecyclerView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/rockerhieu/rv-adapter-states, it supports not only empty view but also loading view and error view. And you can use it without changing the logic of the existing adapter.

Comment: It is nothing but fascinating that there doesn't seem to be a simple `setEmptyView()` method against a `RecyclerView`...

Comment: Here is my answer , please check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58411351/5449220

Comment: @Subby, agree, but `setEmptyView()` also had disadvantage. When loading data, we didn't want to show empty view in `ListView`, but it did. So, we had to implement some logic. Currently I use https://stackoverflow.com/a/48049142/2914140.

Answer (score 347, accepted):

On the same layout where is defined the `RecyclerView`, add the `TextView`:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="@string/no_data_available" />
```

At the `onCreate` or the appropriate callback you check if the dataset that feeds your `RecyclerView` is empty. 
If the dataset is empty, the `RecyclerView` is empty too. In that case, the message appears on the screen.
If not, change its visibility:

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private TextView emptyView;

// ...

recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
emptyView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);

// ...

if (dataset.isEmpty()) {
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else {
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: That does not work for me because the recycler view layout is inflated in the fragment whereas the decision whether to show an normal item layout or an no-items layout is made in the adapter.

Comment: @JJD when using a Fragment, the same thing applies. When you inflate your fragment view you have the recyclerview and then another layout that would be used for your empty view. Usually in my fragments I will have the follow there views:  1) recyclerview, 2) empty view, and 3) progressbar view. I usually pass the adapter whatever the list is, but based on the size of the list i will either hide the recyclerview and show the empty or vice versa. If a recyclerview has an empty list, then it does not do anything with it. You just see an empty view.

Comment: what if the content of recyclerview can be decreased, how to detect it if data changed?

Comment: @stackex The verification must be in the onCreateView callback of the Fragment or onResume of Activity. In this way, the verification will be made immediately before the screen be displayed to the user and will work for both, increasing or decreasing the amount of rows in the dataset.

Comment: Is there no listener that one can attach tot he adapter to check if there is any items int eh adapter?

Comment: @Zapnologica You can do it the other way around: Use an Eventbus (such as greenrobots Eventbus or Otto), then have the Adapter post on the eventbus when the dataset changes. In the fragment all you do is create a method whose parameters correspond to what the Adapter is passing into the Eventbus.post method and then change the layout accordingly. A more simple but also more coupled approach is to create a callback interface in the adapter, and upon creating the adapter have the fragment implement it.

Comment: In the layout I get multiple root tags. What does your full layout file look like?

Comment: @slellis your answer was great (Y),but i want to display empty view without using Textview is it possible ?

Comment: This solution works for me perfectly, I only use the Kotlin, so check the condition like: override fun getItemCount() = dataSet.size.also { showEmpty(dataSet.isEmpty()) }

Answer (score 204):

For my projects I made this solution (`RecyclerView` with `setEmptyView` method):

```
public class RecyclerViewEmptySupport extends RecyclerView {
    private View emptyView;

    private AdapterDataObserver emptyObserver = new AdapterDataObserver() {


        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            Adapter<?> adapter =  getAdapter();
            if(adapter != null && emptyView != null) {
                if(adapter.getItemCount() == 0) {
                    emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    RecyclerViewEmptySupport.this.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                else {
                    emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    RecyclerViewEmptySupport.this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

        }
    };

    public RecyclerViewEmptySupport(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RecyclerViewEmptySupport(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RecyclerViewEmptySupport(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(Adapter adapter) {
        super.setAdapter(adapter);

        if(adapter != null) {
            adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(emptyObserver);
        }

        emptyObserver.onChanged();
    }

    public void setEmptyView(View emptyView) {
        this.emptyView = emptyView;
    }
}
```

And you should use it instead of `RecyclerView` class:

```
<com.maff.utils.RecyclerViewEmptySupport android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    />

<TextView android:id="@+id/list_empty"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Empty"
    />
```

and

```
RecyclerViewEmptySupport list = 
    (RecyclerViewEmptySupport)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list1);
list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
list.setEmptyView(rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_empty));
```

Comment: Did you take this code from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27801394/1276636) or [from here](https://gist.github.com/adelnizamutdinov/31c8f054d1af4588dc5c)?

Comment: @Sufian No, I didn't see that answer, just found the same way. But that code definitely looks prettier than mine:)

Comment: I tried to combine this with the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, it didnt work.   
This is because the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter does not call the onChange (of the AdapterDataObserver), instead it calls the onItem*-methods.   
To make it work add:   
`
        Override  
        public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount)            {  
            //the check  
        }  
  
        Override  
        public void onItemRangeMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition, int itemCount) {  
            //the check  
        }  
  
//etc.. `

Comment: Why do you check if the adapter is null in the observer? if the adapter is null the observer should never be called.

Comment: Might as well become a lib.

Comment: ugh, I must say this is just classic Google BS. I have to implement this just to add an empty view? It should be included in their cr@psh1t SDK! For godsake!

Comment: Never unregister? when rotate devices?

Comment: This will not work if you use DiffUtil to dispatch changes.

Answer (score 73):

Here is a solution using only a custom adapter with a different view type for the empty situation.

```
public class EventAdapter extends 
    RecyclerView.Adapter<EventAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_EVENT = 0;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_DATE = 1;
    private static final int VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY = 2;

    private ArrayList items;

    public EventAdapter(ArrayList items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(items.size() == 0){
            return 1;
        }else {
            return items.size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (items.size() == 0) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY;
        }else{
            Object item = items.get(position);
            if (item instanceof Event) {
                return VIEW_TYPE_EVENT;
            } else {
                return VIEW_TYPE_DATE;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v;
        ViewHolder vh;
        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_EVENT) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.item_event, parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolderEvent(v);
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_DATE) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.item_event_date, parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolderDate(v);
        } else {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.item_event_empty, parent, false);
            vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        }

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(EventAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, 
                                 final int position) {
        int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
        if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_EVENT) {
            //...
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_DATE) {
            //...
        } else if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY) {
            //...
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends ParentViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolderDate extends ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolderDate(View v) {
            super(v);
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolderEvent extends ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolderEvent(View v) {
            super(v);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @sfk92fksdf Why is it error prone? This is the way you're supposed to handle multiple view types in recyclerview

Comment: @billynomates, because `getItemCount()` should be a oneliner but here we have a non-trivial `if` with some hidden logic. This logic also appears awkwardly in `getItemViewType` and god knows where else

Comment: It doesn't need to be one line. If you've got multiple view types, this is the way to do it.

Comment: @sfk92fksdf What do you mean by hidden logic? The code is right up there ▲

Comment: @radu122 by "hidden" I mean non-trivial logic and why it's evil I wrote in my previous comment :)

Comment: I was thinking same :) #great

Comment: in my opinion this answer should be the accepted answer. It really is the way to handle mutliple view types

Comment: Worth noting is that in `onBindViewHolder()` you will have to cast `viewHolder` to specific holder so you can actually access views inside them. Like `ViewHolderDate date = (ViewHolderDate) viewHandler;`. See this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type#comment41176610_26245463

Comment: perfect! Thanks! The point is an empty adapter won't work! it won't call on its onBindViewHolder(), but with setting the item count to 1 it works!

Answer (score 58):

I use ViewSwitcher

```
<ViewSwitcher
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/switcher"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text_empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/list_empty"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</ViewSwitcher>
```

in code you will check cursor/dataset and switch views.

```
void showItems(Cursor items) {
    if (items.size() > 0) {

        mAdapter.switchCursor(items);

        if (R.id.list == mListSwitcher.getNextView().getId()) {
            mListSwitcher.showNext();
        }
    } else if (R.id.text_empty == mListSwitcher.getNextView().getId()) {
        mListSwitcher.showNext();
    }
}
```

Also you can set animations if you wish with a couple lines of code

```
mListSwitcher.setInAnimation(slide_in_left);
mListSwitcher.setOutAnimation(slide_out_right);
```

Answer (score 51):

Since Kevin's answer is not complete.
This is more correct answer if you use `RecyclerAdapter`'s `notifyItemInserted` and `notifyItemRemoved` to update dataset. 
See the Kotlin version another user added below.

Java:

```
mAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {

    @Override
    public void onChanged() {
        super.onChanged();
        checkEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
        checkEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
        super.onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount);
        checkEmpty();
    }

    void checkEmpty() {
        mEmptyView.setVisibility(mAdapter.getItemCount() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Kotlin

```
adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
    override fun onChanged() {
        super.onChanged()
        checkEmpty()
    }

    override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
        super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount)
        checkEmpty()
    }

    override fun onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
        super.onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount)
        checkEmpty()
    }

    fun checkEmpty() {
        empty_view.visibility = (if (adapter.itemCount == 0) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE)
    }
})
```

Comment: This seems good but might not work if you call swapAdapter() or even setAdapter() more than once.

Comment: Great work. don't forget to hide the RecyclerView when showing the label

Answer (score 22):

## RVEmptyObserver

Instead of using a custom `RecyclerView`, extending an `AdapterDataObserver` is a simpler solution that allows setting a custom `View` that is displayed when there are no items in the list:

**Example Usage:**

```
RVEmptyObserver observer = new RVEmptyObserver(recyclerView, emptyView)
rvAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(observer);
```

**Class:**

```
public class RVEmptyObserver extends RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver {
    private View emptyView;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    public RVEmptyObserver(RecyclerView rv, View ev) {
        this.recyclerView = rv;
        this.emptyView    = ev;
        checkIfEmpty();
    }

    private void checkIfEmpty() {
        if (emptyView != null && recyclerView.getAdapter() != null) {
            boolean emptyViewVisible = recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() == 0;
            emptyView.setVisibility(emptyViewVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            recyclerView.setVisibility(emptyViewVisible ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void onChanged() { checkIfEmpty(); }
    public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) { checkIfEmpty(); }
    public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) { checkIfEmpty(); }
}
```

Comment: I believe that it will run faster if you don't call `checkIfEmpty()` in `onChanged()` and `onItemRangeInserted()`

Comment: I agree (and that's what I personally did) but this was just meant to be a starting point for people facing this issue.

Answer (score 10):

On your adapter's `getItemViewType` check if the adapter has 0 elements and return a different viewType if so.

Then on your `onCreateViewHolder` check if the viewType is the one you returned earlier and inflate a diferent view. In this case a layout file with that TextView

**EDIT**

If this is still not working then you might want to set the size of the view programatically like this:

```
Point size = new Point();
((WindowManager)itemView.getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
```

And then when you inflate your view call:

```
inflatedView.getLayoutParams().height = size.y;
inflatedView.getLayoutParams().width = size.x;
```

Comment: Sounds good. However I do not get into `onCreateViewHolder` when my dataset is `null` or empty since I have to return `0` in `getItemCount`.

Comment: Then return 1 if it is null :)

Comment: Works somewhat. Thank you. - Minor detail is that I cannot get the empty list item being **centered vertically** in the recycler view. The text view stays at the top of the screen nonetheless I set `android:layout_gravity="center"` and `android:layout_height="match_parent"` for the parent recycler view.

Comment: It depends on the layout of the row you're using. It should match_parent on it's height. If you can't still make it work, add a global layout listener and set it's layout parameters to have the same height and width as the screen.

Comment: All containers (activity, fragment, linear layout, recycler view, text view) are set to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`. Though the row does not expand to the screen height.

Comment: Remember to pass the parent to the inflated row. How are you inflating your row? Don't pass null as a parent. Pass the recyclerview and false as the 3rd parameter

Comment: I pass the `parent` which comes as parameter from `onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)` to `layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false)` in the adapter.

Comment: You might need to change the layoutparams of the view to have the same width and height of the whole screen. I will change the answer with that info.

Comment: `Display.getSize()` has the disadvantage that it returns the [absolute screen dimension](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize%28android.graphics.Point%29) without consider screen decorations such as the action bar. I am not sure what they mean by "window size".

Comment: Then I think you can just grab the height and width of the recyclerview. You will need to add a globalistener into the empty row

Comment: Do you mean a `OnLayoutChangeListener`?

Comment: `OnGlobalLayoutListener`

Comment: I decided to switch to @slellis approach. I retrieve the data in the fragment in `onViewCreated` and pass it to the adapter. There is the right moment to check the result set and toggle the visibility of the recycler view and the "empty" view. - Thank you anyways - I learned a lot!

Answer (score 9):

Here is my class for show empty view, retry view (when load api failed) and loading progress for `RecyclerView`

```
public class RecyclerViewEmptyRetryGroup extends RelativeLayout {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private LinearLayout mEmptyView;
    private LinearLayout mRetryView;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private OnRetryClick mOnRetryClick;

    public RecyclerViewEmptyRetryGroup(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public RecyclerViewEmptyRetryGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public RecyclerViewEmptyRetryGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewAdded(View child) {
        super.onViewAdded(child);
        if (child.getId() == R.id.recyclerView) {
            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            return;
        }
        if (child.getId() == R.id.layout_empty) {
            mEmptyView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_empty);
            return;
        }
        if (child.getId() == R.id.layout_retry) {
            mRetryView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_retry);
            mRetryView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mRetryView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mOnRetryClick.onRetry();
                }
            });
            return;
        }
        if (child.getId() == R.id.progress_bar) {
            mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        }
    }

    public void loading() {
        mRetryView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void empty() {
        mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRetryView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void retry() {
        mRetryView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void success() {
        mRetryView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public RecyclerView getRecyclerView() {
        return mRecyclerView;
    }

    public void setOnRetryClick(OnRetryClick onRetryClick) {
        mOnRetryClick = onRetryClick;
    }

    public interface OnRetryClick {
        void onRetry();
    }
}
```

**activity_xml**

```
<...RecyclerViewEmptyRetryGroup
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewEmptyRetryGroup">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_empty">
            ...
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_retry">
            ...
        </LinearLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"/>

</...RecyclerViewEmptyRetryGroup>
```

[image]

The source is here https://github.com/PhanVanLinh/AndroidRecyclerViewWithLoadingEmptyAndRetry

Answer (score 9):

Use AdapterDataObserver in custom RecyclerView

**Kotlin:**

RecyclerViewEnum.kt

```
enum class RecyclerViewEnum {
    LOADING,
    NORMAL,
    EMPTY_STATE
}
```

RecyclerViewEmptyLoadingSupport.kt

```
class RecyclerViewEmptyLoadingSupport : RecyclerView {

    var stateView: RecyclerViewEnum? = RecyclerViewEnum.LOADING
        set(value) {
            field = value
            setState()
        }
    var emptyStateView: View? = null
    var loadingStateView: View? = null


    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {}

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {}

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {}


    private val dataObserver = object : AdapterDataObserver() {
        override fun onChanged() {
            onChangeState()
        }

        override fun onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
            super.onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount)
            onChangeState()
        }

        override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
            super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount)
            onChangeState()
        }
    }


    override fun setAdapter(adapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<*>?) {
        super.setAdapter(adapter)
        adapter?.registerAdapterDataObserver(dataObserver)
        dataObserver.onChanged()
    }


    fun onChangeState() {
        if (adapter?.itemCount == 0) {
            emptyStateView?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            loadingStateView?.visibility = View.GONE
            this@RecyclerViewEmptyLoadingSupport.visibility = View.GONE
        } else {
            emptyStateView?.visibility = View.GONE
            loadingStateView?.visibility = View.GONE
            this@RecyclerViewEmptyLoadingSupport.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    private fun setState() {

        when (this.stateView) {
            RecyclerViewEnum.LOADING -> {
                loadingStateView?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                this@RecyclerViewEmptyLoadingSupport.visibility = View.GONE
                emptyStateView?.visibility = View.GONE
            }

            RecyclerViewEnum.NORMAL -> {
                loadingStateView?.visibility = View.GONE
                this@RecyclerViewEmptyLoadingSupport.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                emptyStateView?.visibility = View.GONE
            }
            RecyclerViewEnum.EMPTY_STATE -> {
                loadingStateView?.visibility = View.GONE
                this@RecyclerViewEmptyLoadingSupport.visibility = View.GONE
                emptyStateView?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/emptyView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emptyLabelTv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="empty" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/loadingView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:theme="@style/progressBarBlue" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.peeyade.components.recyclerView.RecyclerViewEmptyLoadingSupport
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

in activity use this way:

```
recyclerView?.apply {
        layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 2)
        emptyStateView = emptyView
        loadingStateView = loadingView
        adapter = adapterGrid
    }

    // you can set LoadingView or emptyView manual
    recyclerView.stateView = RecyclerViewEnum.EMPTY_STATE
    recyclerView.stateView = RecyclerViewEnum.LOADING
```

Comment: If you go with that solution pay attention that using enums is insufficient due to its increased memory allocation size. Use Integer or String depending on your context with appropriate `StringDef` or `IntDef` annotations

Comment: @AndriiArtamonov no it doesn't matter. Use enums - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54893141/2371425

Answer (score 7):

One more way is to use `addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener` which handles appearing/disappearing child views in `RecyclerView`.

```
recyclerView.addOnChildAttachStateChangeListener(new RecyclerView.OnChildAttachStateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildViewAttachedToWindow(@NonNull View view) {
                forEmptyTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildViewDetachedFromWindow(@NonNull View view) {
                forEmptyTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. To add, inside the two methods you can use `recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount()` to decide.

Answer (score 2):

I added `RecyclerView` and alternative `ImageView` to the `RelativeLayout`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/no_active_jobs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_active_jobs" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and then in `Adapter`:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mOrders.size() == 0) {
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    return mOrders.size();
}
```

Comment: how to reach `mRecyclerView` inside the `Adapter`

Comment: It's not good design pattern to tie Adapter to specific Activity. It's better to do that via interfaces

Comment: Also this is causing a layout overdraw, which is not recommended and it could cause some performance issues. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T52v50r-JfE for more details

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use **RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver** and register it in your **recyclerview** after your adapter is initialized.

```
val emptyDataObserver = EmptyDataObserver(recycler_view, empty_data_parent)
yourAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(emptyDataObserver)
```

Where, recycler_view & empty_data_parent are layouts in your activity, constraint those views as you want and make its visibility **GONE**. Then create your own empty dataset view with image & text.

```
 <include
            android:id="@+id/empty_data_parent"
            layout="@layout/item_empty_dataset"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Here's an example of **empty_data_set_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.422"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_empty_dataset_1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title is called when title is placed"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/normal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sub_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Subtitle is called when title is placed. Subtitle is called when title is placed"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/normal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And This **EmptyDataObserver** class that will do the work.

```
import android.view.View
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView


class EmptyDataObserver constructor(rv: RecyclerView?, ev: View?): RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {

    private var emptyView: View? = null
    private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null

    init {
        recyclerView = rv
        emptyView = ev
        checkIfEmpty()
    }


    private fun checkIfEmpty() {
        if (emptyView != null && recyclerView!!.adapter != null) {
            val emptyViewVisible = recyclerView!!.adapter!!.itemCount == 0
            emptyView!!.visibility = if (emptyViewVisible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
            recyclerView!!.visibility = if (emptyViewVisible) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    override fun onChanged() {
        super.onChanged()
        checkIfEmpty()
    }

    override fun onItemRangeChanged(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
        super.onItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define this `Kotlin` extension function in your `utils`:

```
fun <VH : RecyclerView.ViewHolder> RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>.registerDataObserver(onDataChanged: () -> Unit) {
    registerAdapterDataObserver(object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        override fun onChanged() {
            onDataChanged.invoke()
        }

        override fun onItemRangeChanged(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
            onDataChanged.invoke()
        }

        override fun onItemRangeChanged(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int, payload: Any?) {
            onDataChanged.invoke()
        }

        override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
            onDataChanged.invoke()
        }

        override fun onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
            onDataChanged.invoke()
        }

        override fun onItemRangeMoved(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int, itemCount: Int) {
            onDataChanged.invoke()
        }
    })
}
```

**Usage:**
Then you can use it in your code for every adapter like this:

```
adapter.registerDataObserver {
     binding.txtEmpty.setVisible(itemCount == 0)
}
```

Here is `setVisible` helper function:

```
fun View.setVisible(visible: Boolean) {
    visibility = if (visible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just incase you are working with a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter this post works as a charm https://stackoverflow.com/a/39058636/6507009

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display a text view when the recycler view is empty you can do it like this :

```
ArrayList<SomeDataModel> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

RecycleAdapter recycleAdapter =  new RecycleAdapter(getContext(),project_Ideas);

recyclerView..setAdapter(recycleAdapter);

if(arrayList.isEmpty())
{
    emptyTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

I Assume you have TextView

and XML like this

```
 android:visibility="gone"
```

Answer (score 0):

This how to show **empty view** while **filtering and updating RecyclerView using LiveData**

```
    ViewModel.getInstance().getCustomers?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {customerList ->
           //assign your adapter with your list then
        listAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        isListItemEmpty(customerList?.isEmpty())
}
```

Create an interface to communicate between adapter and fragment and register it inside adapter

```
 interface EmptyListener {
            fun isListEmpty(isEmpty: Boolean)
        }
```

Then call it inside publishResults:

```
        dataList?.isEmpty()?.let { mListener?.isListEmpty(it) }
```

Finally inside Fragment implement your interface:

```
 override fun isListEmpty(isEmpty: Boolean) {
        if (isEmpty) {
            your_list?.visibility = View.GONE
            empty_view?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            empty_view?.visibility = View.GONE
            your_list?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
```