# Make empty view take up remaining space after RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to make an empty view that is colored take up the remaining space after a RecyclerView. I've looked at different StackOverflow solutions but nothing works. Essentially I want something like this :

```
________________________
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|    Recycler view      |
|                       |
|  -------------------  |
|    colored empty view |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
_________________________

It should shrink as the RecyclerView grows. 

________________________
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|    Recycler view      |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|                       |
|  -------------------  |
|    colored empty view |
|                       |
|                       |
_________________________
```

However if the RecyclerView exceeds one screen's worth, there should be no empty view. Here's what I have so far:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/bla_bla_layout">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/bla_bla_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <View
        android:background="@color/grayBackground"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:contentDescription="@string/add_bla"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/add_bla_icon"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/primary"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/primary_pressed"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/ripple" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**EDIT**
This is not a duplicate of the mentioned question and you could see this if you read both questions. The solution to my question should be purely xml, layout based. By "empty view" I mean just some colored rectangle BELOW the existing RecyclerView, not a textview that actually says "Empty view" when there's no data in the RecylerView.

Comment: If you're going to downvote my question, please tell me why...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show an empty view with a RecyclerView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217436/how-to-show-an-empty-view-with-a-recyclerview)

Comment: That's not my question at all. His question is really not even a layout question. And believe me I've looked all over and tried numerous solutions to similar problems. If you find one that works that I'll be glad.

Comment: is your recycler view always shorter than one height of a screen and you actually never scroll on it?

Comment: Hm no my RecylerView is always at least one height of a screen. I can tell by the overscroll effect

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475178/how-do-i-make-wrap-content-work-on-a-recyclerview

Comment: What's preventing you from specifying the background color for FrameLayout and getting rid of the the empty View once and for all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recycler view calculate its height at runtime and we uses LinearLayoutManager to specify its height and width.

But problem is that, right now LinearLayoutManager does not support wrap_content it uses always match_parent for it's height.

So you have to use this [LinearLayoutManager](https://github.com/serso/android-linear-layout-manager) not android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.

copy above java class in your package and use it like below,

```
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
// if it has fixed size
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

I tested it and its working as you need.

Comment: This works thanks. However I used the simpler extended version of LinearLayoutManger here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649406/nested-recycler-view-height-doesnt-wrap-its-content/28510031#28510031 that also takes into account swiping, drag sorting, and item decorations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/bla_bla_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/bla_bla_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/array_sample" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/grayBackground" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The RecyclerView just takes up the whole space. In any case I have to use FrameLayout I think because of the FAB.

Comment: You could just place the `LinearLayout` inside of a `FrameLayout` though, right?

Comment: Yep I tried that as well. It had the same effect. RecyclerView just took up all the space.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could accomplish with a `RelativeLayout` using some align commands.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/blue"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I included the `FrameLayout` because you mentioned in another comment that you needed it to use with a FAB.

If you load this into AndroidStudio and start setting sample widths (50dp, 150dp, 300dp...) for the height of the `RecyclerView` you will see the `View` below it start to adjust its height as well.

Comment: Again doesn't work because the RecyclerView takes up the whole space. I tried setting the height of the View to 0 and weight to 1 but that didn't work. Tried the same with the RecyclerView while keeping View at match_parent height but that didn't work either. My RecyclerView contents are set dynamically. I don't know what the issue but thanks for the try.

Comment: So do you have items in the RecyclerView that take up the whole screen? If you have more than enough items in your collection to fill the screen I don't see how this would be possible.

Comment: No for now I'm just testing with a single item that takes up about a tenth of the screen. But when I try to scroll I tell from the overscroll effect that the RecyclerView is taking up the whole screen.

Comment: This won't work because RecyclerView does not update it's height when new elements are drawn. But there is a work around, all you need is to leave RecyclerView for last on the file, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a different color in the remaining space, set the `FrameLayout`'s background to the desired color and set the `RecyclerView` item's `layout` background to white.

This will result in the remaining space in a separate color and the length of the populated items in `recyclerView` will be white just as you need.

If you want some other view in the remaining space like a textView or an ImageView I guess you will have to extend `RecyclerView class` and `override` the method which calculates it's height.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom LinearLayoutManager hopefully its solve your problem.

use this code in your activity

```
 RecycleView rv= (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
   CustomLinearLayoutManager lm= new CustomLinearLayoutManager(mActivity);
    lm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    lm.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv.setLayoutManager(lm);
```

Here is my CustomLinearLayoutManager

```
public class CustomLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

public CustomLinearLayoutManager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

@Override
public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state,
                      int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
    final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
    final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
    final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
    final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);

    measureScrapChild(recycler, 0,
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            mMeasuredDimension);

    int width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
    int height = mMeasuredDimension[1];

    switch (widthMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            width = widthSize;
            break;
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    switch (heightMode) {
        case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
        case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            height = heightSize;
            break;
        case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
    }

    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                               int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
    try {
        View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
        if (view != null) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
            int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
            view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
            measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth();
            measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight();
            recycler.recycleView(view);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}