# SwipeRefreshLayout doesn't refresh on swipe when list size is zero

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I am using SwipeRefreshLayout for my recyclerview.I am showing data in recyclerview by making an api call and i am calling that api on swipe refresh.The issue I am having is that if list size is zero than swipe refresh is not working.I want to make api call on swipe refresh even when list size is zero so that list gets updated if any new data is there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/datalist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/homebackground"
            android:clipToPadding="false"

            android:paddingBottom="8dp"

            />



    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNoData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="No orders yet"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code

```
   swiperefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                callLoginApi();
            }
        });
 private void callLoginApi() {

    APICALL(in, new Callback<Orssaf>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<Orssaf> result) {
                swiperefresh.setRefreshing(false);

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException e) {

                swiperefresh.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }
```

Adapter

```
public class OrderHistoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OrderHistoryAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<OrderDetailsData> orders;
    public OrderHistoryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<OrderDetailsData> order) {
        mContext = context;
        orders = order;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_foodvitecurrentorder, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        OrderDetailsData order = orders.get(position);
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(order.getSenderImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.profile_img).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(holder.profileimage);
        holder.itemscount.setText("dfg"));
        holder.pricecount.setText("$fsdf"));
        holder.ordertime.setText("sdgsdg");
        holder.message.setText("greg");

        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return orders.size();
    }
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private CircularImageView profileimage;
        private TextView status, message, itemscount, pricecount, ordertime
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            profileimage = (CircularImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileimage);
            status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
            message = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
            itemscount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemscount);
            pricecount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pricecount);
            ordertime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ordertime);

        }
    }
}
```

UPDATED according to answer..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.foodviteseller.co.foodviteseller.views.RecyclerViewEmptySupport
            android:id="@+id/datalist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/homebackground"
            android:clipToPadding="false"

            android:paddingBottom="8dp"

            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emptyView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="EmptyList"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <!--<include layout="@layout/no_data_layout" />-->

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNoData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="No orders yet"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code

```
  datalist = (RecyclerViewEmptySupport) v.findViewById(R.id.datalist);

 private void callLoginApi() {

    APICALL(in, new Callback<Orssaf>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<Orssaf> result) {
                swiperefresh.setRefreshing(false);
              if (orders.size() > 0) {
    orderAdapter = new OrderHistoryAdapter(mContext, orders);
    datalist.setAdapter(orderAdapter);
} else {
    emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   datalist.setEmptyView(emptyView);
    tvNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tvNoData.setText("No orders yet");
}

                }
            }
            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException e) {

                swiperefresh.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You have to post your adapter class and the onRefreshListener implementation.

Comment: @MalithLakshan posted

Comment: Can we see `callLoginApi()` ?

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier yeah..added tht now in code above

Comment: In `callLoginAPI()` you need to add all your element to your `ArrayList` and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier I am doing tht..the issue is that SwipeRefreshLayout doesn't refresh on swipe when list size is zero..

Comment: Can you show the initialization of the swipe ? In the MainActivity.

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier wht initialization i have to do??  I have to just find the layout.. `swiperefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);`

Comment: Have you try to add `Log` before and after the `callLoginApi()`, just to know if you in the `refresh()` ?

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier i'll check tht but i don't think onrefresh getting called when list size is zero..

Comment: @RaphaelTeyssandier onrefresh not getting called if list size is zero

Comment: Yeah i think i know why, i'll post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's, like you said, you list is empty, so no `VIew` to swipe, you need to add an emptyView like with `listView.setEmptyView()`. But with the `RecyclerView` no `setEmptyView()` exists so just follow this post :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30415582/4854450

That's work for me.

So you XML gona be like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/datalist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/homebackground"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNoData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="No orders yet"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT:
when list is empty

```
    EmptyAdapter adapter = new EmptyAdapter();
    datalist.setAdapter(adapter);


public class EmptyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: not working..still its not refershing if list size is zero

Comment: So you have create a class how extends from `RecyclerView` and change it into the XML ? `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` to `com.myproject.MyRecyclerView` ?

Comment: in adapter i also changed recyclerview to customview

Comment: Don't set you adapter in the `callLoginApi` do it after the `findViewById()`

Comment: I want to set adapter only after i get data from api as i am passing data to adapter

Comment: No, set you adapter in the initialization with the `setEmptyView()` like in my post in few second.

Comment: Setting empty adapter works for me ..please update your answer so that i can mark it as correct answer..thanu for ur time..

Comment: Done, no problem, I'm here for that.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of your `RelativeLayout` subviews. Your top view in -case of no list items- is the TextView, so it's blocking the SwipeRefreshLayout. Changing the order should work because of the Z-ordering of the views is defined by the order the views are added. check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4685019/2185634)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvNoData"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="No orders yet"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/datalist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/homebackground"
        android:clipToPadding="false"

        android:paddingBottom="8dp"

        />



</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: now working even if i remove textview tvNoData..it doesn't refreshes if list size is zero

Comment: *NOT working even if i remove textview tvNoData..it doesn't refreshes if list size is zero

Comment: Does the loading animation appear?

Comment: onrefresh not called if list size is zero

Comment: do you change visibility of the SwipeRefreshLayout or RecyclerView if there are no list items?