# Empty View on a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In an app I am working on, I am using a Recycler View to show a list of items. I would like the list to display some view (For example, a text view) when the list is empty. I know that with ListViews, one could call `setEmptyView`, but RecyclerView has no such method.

I have tried setting the visibility of a view to GONE, and making it visible when the RecyclerView dataset is empty, but adding any view to the layout file where the RecyclerView is defined leads to an error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean 
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.shouldIgnore()' on a null 
object reference
```

What is the best way to go about what I am doing?

For more info, the RecyclerView is held inside a Fragment, and the layout is inflated in the onCreateView function.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grocerylist, container, false);

    rv = view.findViewById(R.id.grocery_list);

    dh = new DatabaseHandler(view.getContext());

    dataset = dh.getGroceries();

    // Set the adapter
    if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

        adapter = new GroceryListRecyclerViewAdapter(dataset,mListener,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new SimpleTouchHelperCallback(adapter);
    ith = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
    ith.attachToRecyclerView(rv);

    DividerItemDecoration div = new DividerItemDecoration(rv.getContext(),
            DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);

    rv.addItemDecoration(div);

    return view;
}
```

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/grocery_list" android:name="com.github.jlcarveth.grocer.layout.fragment.GroceryListFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"  tools:context="com.github.jlcarveth.grocer.layout.fragment.GroceryListFragment"   tools:listitem="@layout/grocery_item"/>
```

Comment: Could you put your activity or fragment?

Comment: That's not a complete sentence. ^^^

Comment: update your answer with the code of your fragment and the xml layout

Comment: I put the answer below :)

Comment: Use AdapterDataObserver, see this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/52716769/4797289

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated your code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:name="com.github.jlcarveth.grocer.layout.fragment.GroceryListFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
tools:context="com.github.jlcarveth.grocer.layout.fragment.GroceryListFragment"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/grocery_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/grocery_item" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="NO DATA AVAILABLE" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Your Fragment:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_grocerylist, container, false);

    rv = view.findViewById(R.id.grocery_list);
    TextView emptyView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);

    dh = new DatabaseHandler(view.getContext());

    dataset = dh.getGroceries();


     Context context = view.getContext();
     RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rv;
     recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

     adapter = new GroceryListRecyclerViewAdapter(dataset,mListener,this);
     recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


    ItemTouchHelper.Callback callback = new SimpleTouchHelperCallback(adapter);
    ith = new ItemTouchHelper(callback);
    ith.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    DividerItemDecoration div = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(),
            DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);

    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(div);


    if (dataset.isEmpty()){
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
         recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }



    return view;
}
```

Comment: This is the working solution with the easiest changes to my current code!

Answer (score 1):

Add a textview to your layout.  At the same level as the RecyclerView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/empty_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:visibility="gone"
android:text="@string/no_data_available" />
```

At the onCreate or the appropriate callback check to see if the dataset that feeds your RecyclerView is empty. If it is then the RecyclerView is empty too. In that case, the message appears on the screen. If not, change its visibility:

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private TextView emptyView;

// ...

recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
emptyView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);

// ...

if (dataset.isEmpty()) {
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else {
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: I'd get an error for multiple root tags if I tried to put a TextView on the same level as the RecyclerView

Comment: Just put these two inside a RelativeLayout .

Comment: then put them inside of a layout so neither one is the root

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for developers using Kotlin and databinding in their Android project.

custom_recyclerview_empty_support.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Recycler view -->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!-- Empty view -->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_text_view"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Empty View" />

    <!-- Retry view -->
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/retry_linear_layout_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/retry_text_view"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/views_pad_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/views_pad_vertical"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/views_pad_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/views_pad_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:text="Retry View" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/retry_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/retry_button" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    <!--  Loading view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/loading_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

The fragment class where I am using this Custom RecyclerView class

```
     <app.ui.widgets.RecyclerViewEmptySupport
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Creating a Custom RecyclerView class :

```
class RecyclerViewEmptySupport(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) :
ConstraintLayout(context, attrs) {

private val binding: CustomRecyclerviewEmptySupportBinding
val recyclerView: RecyclerView

init {
    this.binding =
        CustomRecyclerviewEmptySupportBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)
    this.recyclerView = binding.recyclerView
}

fun updateViews(
    loading: Boolean = false,
    retry: Boolean = false,
    empty: Boolean = false,
    success: Boolean = false
) {
    binding.recyclerView.setVisibleOrGone(success)
    binding.emptyTextView.setVisibleOrGone(empty)
    binding.retryLinearLayoutView.setVisibleOrGone(retry)
    binding.loadingView.setVisibleOrGone(loading)
}

// Empty view
fun showEmptyMessage(message: String) {
    updateViews(empty = true)
    binding.emptyTextView.text = message
}

// Retry view
fun showRetryView(message: String, callback: () -> Unit) {
    updateViews(retry = true)

    binding.retryTextView.text = message
    binding.retryButton.setOnClickListener { callback() }
}
}
```

The Fragment/Activity class can manage the Views visibility and setting data to views , like this :

When api is to be called , call this block of code ,

```
 binding.myRecyclerView.updateViews(loading = true)
 getDataFromRepository()
```

When data is empty in api response , call this,

```
binding.myRecyclerView.showEmptyMessage("No Items Message")
```

When data exists in api , call this ,

```
 list.addAll(apiList)
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

 binding.myRecyclerView.updateViews(success = true)
```

When there is some error in api response , call this

```
 binding.myRecyclerView.showRetryView("Unable to get data at the moment.") { getDataFromRepository() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go for a Relative layout.

```
<Relative layout>
    <Recycler View/>

    <Text View/>
</Relative layout
```

As the `array` is empty

```
  RecyclerView.GONE
   TextView.VISIBLE
```

and if the `array` is having some data

```
  RecyclerView.VISIBLE
  TextView.GONE
```

In my case, I am following this only.

If doesn't work, I'll send you my code.

Comment: it doesn't works for me

Answer (score 0):

When I faced this issue, while surfing the web I found useful gist https://gist.github.com/sheharyarn/5602930ad84fa64c30a29ab18eb69c6e.

Here shown how to implement empty view in elegant way by defining data observer.