# Are Enum classes in Kotlin "expensive" for Android as in Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, enums

- Are **Enum** classes in Kotlin "expensive" for Android as Java?.
- Is it still stand to use `@IntDefs` or `@StringDefs` in Kotlin?.

When I decompile Kotlin Enum class to Java class, there still used Java Enums in the low level, which are not recommended for use in Android Development, and this made me think about this.

Comment: Kotlin runs on the same JVM that Java does and compiles to similar byte code, so I can't imagine that enums in Kotlin behave any differently than enums in Java.

Comment: That being said, eliminating enums from your Android code falls under the category of micro-optimizations, meaning unless your app is going to be large and you know the memory footprint is going to be a problem, it's not worth fussing over. Besides, the only thing you really need to do anyway is configure ProGuard to convert your enums to integer constants at compile time.

Comment: @Abion47 I didn't know ProGuard could do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *Are Enum classes in Kotlin "expensive" for Android as Java?.* Could be. I doubt whether kotlin will be able to do any optimization that java cannot.
2. *Is it still stand to use @IntDefs or @StringDefs in Kotlin?.* - Not really. This is a polarising subject and many in the Android world(including me) believe that using enums should be the preferred way. I encourage you to read the following links to get a better idea.

[Twitter thread by Jake Wharton](https://twitter.com/jakewharton/status/551876948469620737?lang=en)

[An article by Diane Hackborn and the comments](https://plus.google.com/+DianneHackborn/posts/YDykw2hstUu)

[Somwhat witty reddit thread talking about optimization of enums and such](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/7so7ne/you_should_strictly_avoid_using_enums_on_android/)

And the following answers by Jake Wharton are interesting.

> Does lint support kotlin typedefs? (Lint for Kotlin won't be fully
>   supported until AS 3.1, and we're on 3.0 still)
>
> Do you mean typealias? If so, yes.
>
> Will I get a lint warning for an exhaustive when when I do a return
>   when(intDef) { .. } and accidentally omit one of the the possible
>   types?
>
> An else will always be required here. Not sure about the lint warning
>   though.
>
> Does AS have an intention (alt + enter to quickly add all variants of
>   the intDef?
>
> Yes.
>
> Like right now, instead of shipping features, we're discussing when
>   this micro-optimization should be used!
>
> Summation of the entire enum conversation since about 2012!
>
> I'm also wondering if a sealed class where each implementation is an
>   object has some perf gains over an enum
>
> None. It's effectively the exact same thing as an enum.

Comment: I'd expect "a sealed class where each implementation is an object" to be worse if anything (more classes to load and keep in memory).

Comment: true and we use it everywhere :)

Comment: So.. In Kotlin, choosing between enum and @IntDef/@StringDef, you prefer to use Enums right?