# How to create an empty view in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am working with a Fragment that handles a RecyclerView with different adapters, but when I try to show my emptyView TextView in the RecyclerView it simply stops the RecyclerView from working properly.

I created the following filter in my adapter:

```
/**
     * Method that filters the data using the onQueryTextSubmit and onQueryTextChange.
     *
     * @return a Filter class that calls the method performFiltering of the FilterResults class
     * and this method applies the filter and returns a list with the resulting data filtered.
     */
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence querySample) {

            if (emptyView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            /*
             * Verifies the value of the sampleNameSearched and compares the data.
             */
            if (querySample == null) {
                // Updates the recyclerView with the sampleList.
                sampleListFiltered.submitList(sampleList);
                // holder.sampleView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(inflater.getContext(), R.color.BaseColor_1));
            } else {

                // Cleans the accentuation, letter case and other symbols of the querySample.
                sampleNameSearched = Normalizer.normalize(querySample.toString(), Normalizer.Form.NFD)
                        .replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "").toLowerCase();

                // Creates the list that will save the filtered samples.
                List<Sample> filteredSampleList = new LinkedList<>();

                // Gets the data filtered in the for loop.
                for (Sample sample : sampleList) {

                    // Cleans the accentuation, letter case and other symbols.
                    String sampleName = Normalizer.normalize(sample.getName(), Normalizer.Form.NFD)
                            .replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "").toLowerCase();

                    // Adds the sample that matches the filter in the filteredSampleList.
                    if (sampleName.contains(sampleNameSearched)) {
                        filteredSampleList.add(sample);
                    }
                }

                // Updates the RecyclerView.
                sampleListFiltered.submitList(filteredSampleList);

                // TODO: Find a solution for not showing the emptyView instantly (not entering the onBindViewHolder).
                /*
                 * if filteredSampleList is empty, shows the emptyView with the proper message.
                 */
                if (filteredSampleList.isEmpty()) {
                    // Updates the RecyclerView.
                    emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    if (emptyView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }

            }

            // Returns the filterResults.
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = sampleListFiltered;
            return filterResults;
        }

        // Publish the results on the RecyclerView.
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults filterResults) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```

I cannot find out why my emptyView.setVisibility() sometimes works and others simply doesn't.

My layout is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@id/search_sample_field"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sample_folder_selector">

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/sample_search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@drawable/search_box_border"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:queryHint="@string/sample_search" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/ListNavigatorRecyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ButtonPanel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_sample_field"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyListNavigatorView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ButtonPanel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_sample_field"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/ButtonPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/BaseColor_4"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/remove_sample_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_delete"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

            style="@style/IconButton" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Just to make sure that you understand the problem you can see some prints of the problem below:

**What was supposed to happen**:

Step 1 - Filter:
[Filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohf5C.png)

Step 2 - Writing a sample that doesn't exist:
[Sample that doesn't exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ3L8.png)

Step 3 - Removing the wrong character:
[The wrong character removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj8jn.png)

**What is happening right now (not supposed to happen)**:

Step 1 - Filter (working):
[Filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohf5C.png)

Step 2 - Writing a sample that doesn't exist (not showing the emptyView):
[Not showing the emptyView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZMQM.png)

Step 3 - Removing the wrong character (not showing the sample nor the bold character):
[Not showing the sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFnEz.png)

If I press the search button on the keyboard it works, but it was intended to work without pressing the search button...

Can someone help me with this problem?

I used a toast, and the toast works, but when it comes to using any kind of set method in the performFiltering or layout that requires a set method it seems that Android somehow losses its working flow.

I tried the following implementations:

[How to show an empty view with a RecyclerView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217436/how-to-show-an-empty-view-with-a-recyclerview)

https://alexzh.com/how-to-setemptyview-to-recyclerview/

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/3bjnxi/best_way_to_handle_recyclerview_empty_state/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to solve this problem?**

I created an EmptyRecyclerView that extends the RecyclerView behaviours and added an updateEmptyView() method that verifies how many items I have in my RecyclerView and updates the view accordingly. My solution was based on this [answer by maff91](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30415582/10055296). And another source that helped me solve the problem is [this Google Application](https://github.com/commons-app/ShootMe/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/xyztouristattractions/ui/AttractionsRecyclerView.java) that creates an EmptyView message like the one I needed.

My thanks to maff91 and the Google Application that has the same behaviour.