# Alternate for a listview with single row

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ImageView` with a `TextView` and Button. I have it currently in a custom list view, but I noticed now that I don't need to show more as one element (object). So I actually don't need a `Listview` to show the row (list entry). How can I show the list entry without a `Listview`?

Comment: I think you can `<include .. />` it in your current layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the elements of your custom listview item into a Layout, e.g. LinearLayout and simply add it to your activity's layout where you needed it.
You can set an OnClickListener for that layout, so user can click the whole thing.

Comment: But where can I define the position of the LinearLayout in my MainActivity?

Comment: That depends on your MainActivity's layout. You can treat Layout elements like View elements within an outer Layout. If you post your MainActivity's layout and tell me where you want the LinearLayout placed, I can surely point it out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `ListActivity`. Then you can set up empty view for list. Here some tutorial: [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html) and [ListView Tips](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/06/20/listview-tips-tricks-1-handle-emptiness/).
Also you can implement that logic with Recycler view by yourself or use library.
Here is solution [from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414173/equivalent-of-listview-setemptyview-in-recyclerview)