# recyclerview setEmptyView implementation - android

Tags: android, view, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, observable

I'm trying to implement a setEmptyView method by creating a custom recyclerview class with an AdapterDataObserver, like some users described here:

[Equivalent of ListView.setEmptyView in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414173/equivalent-of-listview-setemptyview-in-recyclerview/27801394#27801394)

The problem is it's not working for me. When the list is full of data, I can see the list items perfectly but whenever the list is empty, I can't see my empty view.

Here is my custom recyclerview:

```
package bikurim.silverfix.com.bikurim.utils.general;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Created by David on 16/07/2016.
 *
 * A custom implementation of the RecyclerView class for supporting setEmptyView() method
 *
 * @author David Lasry
 */
public class FamilyRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    private View emptyView;
    private AdapterDataObserver emptyObserver = new AdapterDataObserver() {

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            checkIfEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount, Object payload) {
            checkIfEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            checkIfEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            checkIfEmpty();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            checkIfEmpty();
        }
    };
    public FamilyRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public FamilyRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public FamilyRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAdapter(Adapter adapter) {
        super.setAdapter(adapter);

        if(adapter != null) {
            adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(emptyObserver);
        }

        checkIfEmpty();
    }

    public void setEmptyView(View emptyView) {
        this.emptyView = emptyView;
    }

    private void checkIfEmpty() {
        if(emptyView != null && getAdapter() != null) {
            final boolean isEmpty = getAdapter().getItemCount() == 0;
            emptyView.setVisibility(isEmpty ? VISIBLE : GONE);
            setVisibility(isEmpty ? GONE : VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the part in my activity where I inflate a view from layout resource and set it to be my empty view:

```
FamilyRecyclerView recyclerView = (FamilyRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
View emptyView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.empty_layout, null);
recyclerView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

I debugged it a little bit and emptyView is not null, which means the inflation is successful.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you haven't added your emptyView to the hierarchy anywhere, when you inflate it you set the parent as `null` and while you toggle its visibility when it is in the listView you never actually add it as a child of any view. As a result, it exists but it isn't displayed on the screen. To get it show up you can inflate it with a parent view or add it to the parent view after inflation:

```
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.empty_layout, contentView);
```

or

```
contentView.addView(emptyView);
```

(The `contentView` is the view that is holding your recyclerView)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I finally decided to just put the empty view inside my xml layout and get the reference to it in my activity for animation purposes.

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed it! that is also a valid approach.